# Installing libfmt-dev in Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

How to install libfmt-dev on Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed the steps in [here](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libfmt-dev)
And I tried

`sudo apt install libfmt-dev`

But I got package not found error.

Comment: libfmt-dev package is not available in Ubuntu 16.04.  It is available in Ubuntu releases 18.04 and higher than it.

Comment: @KKPatel libfmt-dev package in 18.04 has no dependencies that are required to install it.

Comment: @Karel I agree with you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the libfmt-dev package from Ubuntu 18.04 in Ubuntu 16.04. libfmt-dev has no dependencies, so you can download it and install it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update  
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fmtlib/libfmt-dev_4.0.0+ds-2_amd64.deb   
sudo apt install ./libfmt-dev_4.0.0+ds-2_amd64.deb
```

If you want to also install the fast type-safe C++ formatting library -- documentation package (*libfmt-doc*) run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install libjs-sphinxdoc 
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fmtlib/libfmt-doc_4.0.0+ds-2_all.deb  
sudo apt install ./libfmt-doc_4.0.0+ds-2_all.deb
```